# Sitecore Powershell script for changing item template in all language versions

Tags: powershell-extensions

i want to change the item template in all language version and retain the data.
I have tried this :

```
$rootItem = Get-Item master:"/sitecore/content/home/"
$sourceTemplate = Get-Item "{E6787535-1C98-4C18-9D45-68DF4837BEF8}";
$targetTemplate = Get-Item "{CB1DACB2-0B85-4D92-9BC7-5EC0CF208E5F}";

 

Get-ChildItem $rootItem.FullPath -recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq $sourceTemplate.Name } | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ItemTemplate -Item $_ -TemplateItem $targetTemplate `
        -FieldsToCopy @{'Module ID'="AccordionModuleId" ;'Module Category' = "AccordionModuleCategory"; 'Module Title' = "AccordionModuleTitle"; 'Items' = "AccordionModuleLinks" }
}
```

But it works fine only for en language and for rest of the languages it is having empty field values.
Any way of achieving this?

Comment: At the following link you can see the documentation lists that the `Language` and `Version` parameters can be used. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items#command-parameters

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did something in the past for updating all templates, and got through by using this within my loop :

`$masterDatabase = [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetDatabase("master");`

your loop and conditions {

```
$actualTemplate = $master.Templates["Path/To/YourTemplate"];
$_.ChangeTemplate($actualTemplate);
```

}

Hope it helps, cheers !